# Eclipse:error missing (,}

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
package com.elitiv.calculatorvamalv2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  private EditText editYear;
  private EditText editCapacity;
  private EditText Result;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
    TextView Year = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Year);
    TextView Capacity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Capacity);
    editYear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editYear);
    editCapacity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCapacity);
    Result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Result);
    Button   calc =(Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
    final RadioButton RadioD = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioD);
    final RadioButton RadioB = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioB);
    
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double editYear = editYear.getText().toString();
            double editCapacity = editYear.getText().toString();
            
            if(RadioB.isChecked()){
                switch(editYear){
                case 2014:
                    if(editCapacity >0 && NCapacity <1000){
                        Result = editCapacity*0.57;
                    
                }
                    if(editCapacity >1000 && editCapacity <1500){
                        Result = editCapacity*0.67;
                    
                }
                    if(editCapacity >1501 && editCapacity <2000){
                        Result = editCapacity*1.00;
                    
                }
                break;
            }
            
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
});


}
}
```

I'm trying to make a simple app that is adding 2 values by a condition, itdidn't compile the app yet because of 2 errors:

> Syntax error on token ")", { expected  MainActivity.java   /CalculatorVamalV2/src/com/elitiv/calculatorvamalv2 line 65 Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody MainActivity.java   /CalculatorVamalV2/src/com/elitiv/calculatorvamalv2 line 86 Java Problem

When android studio gives me a problem i switch to eclipse and viceversa.

Comment: The error messages are very descriptive. Check file `MainActivity.java`, line 65 and fix it. Similar for line 86.

Comment: Where is line 65? Line 86?

Comment: Take a look at onOptionsItemSelected... (at the end.. maybe an extra ")")

Comment: @Code-Guru the code includes the package name, so you may assume this is the whole content of the file. I copied/pasted in my text editor (Notepad++ in Windows) and spot the errors in both lines 65 and 86 with no problems.

Comment: oh,ty a lot guys and sorry for taking youre time with such a pitty mistake of mine,best to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are very descriptive. Check file `MainActivity.java`, line 65 and fix it. Similar for line 86.

Anyway, these are the errors:

> Syntax error on token ")", { expected MainActivity.java /CalculatorVamalV2/src/com/elitiv/calculatorvamalv2 line 65 Java Problem

You missed a close brace `}` in the inner class definition:

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    TextView Year = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Year);
    TextView Capacity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Capacity);
    editYear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editYear);
    editCapacity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCapacity);
    Result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Result);
    Button   calc =(Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
    final RadioButton RadioD = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioD);
    final RadioButton RadioB = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioB);

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double editYear = editYear.getText().toString();
            double editCapacity = editYear.getText().toString();

            if(RadioB.isChecked()){
                switch(editYear){
                case 2014:
                    if(editCapacity >0 && NCapacity <1000){
                        Result = editCapacity*0.57;

                }
                    if(editCapacity >1000 && editCapacity <1500){
                        Result = editCapacity*0.67;

                }
                    if(editCapacity >1501 && editCapacity <2000){
                        Result = editCapacity*1.00;

                }
                break;
            }

        }
                } // <-- add this here
    });
}
```

> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody MainActivity.java /CalculatorVamalV2/src/com/elitiv/calculatorvamalv2 line 86 Java Problem

You don't have an anonymous class here, so there's no need to have `);`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Besides this, you have an additional brace `}` at the end of the definition of your class.

---

## How to avoid these problems?

[**Indent your code**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style). Since you're using eclipse and android development studio (based on Eclipse), you have this shortcut to let the IDE auto format the code automatically for you: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quick and easy way to identify } ) and ; errors in Eclipse.  I can see your spacing and indentation is off and not standardized.

While in Eclipse, highlight your entire class, or press ctrl-a.

Then hold down shift-ctrl and press f.   This automatically formats your code and indents properly.  This should make it easy to find out where you are missing the }.  I know this works in the Windows build of Eclipse.

Comment: This doesn't point out the actual error. Note how the other answer points out the actual error _and_ shows how to format code.